# Corrct method for inputting radio button value in PHP in a bootstrap 3 document

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button, w3c-validation

I'm having html5 serialization and improper attribute placement error on

> input

element in the following code:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend>Choose Color</legend>
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="color" id="blue" value="Blue"
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['form']['color']) == "Blue") echo "checked"; ?>/>          
            Blue
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="color" id="green" value="Green"
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['form']['color']) == "Green") echo "checked"; ?>/>        
    Green
          </label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
```

What is the correct method to put the radio button value straight into the bootstrap document.

Any resolution shall be thankfully appreciated.

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['form']['color']) == "Green")` - false positive. Break that down in 2 parts.

Comment: @Fred -ii-  breaking the PHP code into two parts doesn't resolve the validation error. I want to resolve the validation error first.

Comment: you've an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
if(isset($_SESSION['form']['color']) == "Green")
```

Use

```
if(isset($_SESSION['form']['color']) &&  $_SESSION['form']['color'] === "Green")
```

Comment: that's not the resolution on validation.

Comment: How do you keep color value?

Comment: I don't store the value in database. I guess the the problem is related to document type declaration. Any idea?

Comment: If you use <!DOCTYPE HTML>  rignt syntax <input ... checked/> If use <!DOCTYPE XHTML> right syntax <input ... checked="checked"/>

Comment: i use html5 that is <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

html5 doesn't support serialization of `PHP value` for certain input element type like

> select &
>   radio,
>   etc..

straightly from bootstrap document and that's really very bad.